# Unreferenced Formal Parameter Qt Game

Tags: qt

```
Game::Game(QWidget *parent){
// set up the screen
setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
setFixedSize(1024,768);
```

Warning C4100: 'parent':unreferenced Formal Parameter

Comment: We will not google it for you. Please do your debugging and ask proper questions :)

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: This is just the warning parent is not used, google to learn more

Answer (score -1):

The parent parameter is not used, if `Game` class is derived from `QDialog`, then it should be used to initilize `QDialog`, as :

```
Game::Game(QWidget *parent):QDialog(parent)
```

Comment: Why do you think Game is derived from QDialog? And the code in question is from cpp...

Comment: As I don't know the parent class of Game, so I just suppose it derived from QDialog, In my code I means : Game:Game(QWidget *parent):<parent class of Game>(parent)